# How to generate one-time-use links? Any CMS or framework solutions?

Tags: content-management-system, hyperlink

I'm making a site for a writers management company. They get tons of script submissions every day from prospective and often unsolicited writers. The new site will allow a prospective writer to submit a short logline / sample of his or her idea. This idea gets sent to an email account at the management group. If the management group likes what they see, they want to be able to approve that submission from within the email and have a unique link dispatched to the submitter to upload their full script. This link would either only work once, or only for a certain amount of time so that only the intended recipient could use it.

So, can anyone point me in the direction of some sort of (I'm assumine PHP + mySQL) CMS or framework that could accomplish this? I've searched a lot, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to phrase this query to a search engine.

I have moderate programming experience, but not much with PHP outside of some simple Wordpress hacks.

Thanks!

Comment: Only working once is a bad idea.  If the client has any sort of error uploading their document, they get screwed and you have to go through the process again.  Time limited windows are better, or a multi step process that ensure the link ceases to be functional only after a successful upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just give you general guidelines on a simple way to construct such a system.

I assume that the Writer is somehow Registered into the system, and his/her profile contains a valid mail address.

So, when he submits the sample, you would create an entry on the "Sample" table. Then you would mail a Manager with the sample and a link. This link would point to a script giving the database "id" of the sample as a parameter (this script should verify that the manager is logged on -- if not, show the login screen and after successful login redirect him back).

This script would then be aware of the Manager's intention to allow the Writer to submit his work. Now the fun begins.

There are many possibilities:

1. You can create an entry in an appropriate "SubmitAuthorizations" DB table containing the id of the Writer and the date this authorization was given (ie, the date when the row was added to your DB). Then you simply send a mail to the Writer with a link like "upload.php?id=42", where the id is the authorization id. This script would check if the logged user is the correct Writer, and if he is within the allowed timeframe (by comparing the stored "authorization date" and the current date).
2. The next is the one I prefer: without a special table just for handling something trivial (let's say you will never want to "edit" an authorization, nor "cancel" it, but it may still "expire"). You simply simply give the Writer a link with 2 parameters: the **date the authorization was given** and an **authorization key**, like: "upload.php?authDate=20091030&key=87a62d726ef7..."

Let me explain how it works.

The script would first verify if the Writer is logged on (if not, show the login page with a redirection after successful login).

So, now it's time to validate the request: that is, check if this is not a "forged" link. How to do this? It's just a "smart" way of construction this authorization key.

You can do something like:

```
key = hash(concat(userId, ";", authDate, ";", seed));
```

Well, here **hash()** is what we call a "one-way function", like MD5, SHA1, etc. Then **concat()** is simply a string concatenation function. Finally **seed** is something like a "master password", completely random and that will not change (for if you change it all the issued links would stop working) just to increase security -- let's say a hacker correctly guesses you are using MD5 (which is easy) and the he tries to hack your system by hashing some combinations of the username and the date.

Also, for a request to be valid, it must be in the correct time frame.

So, if both the key is valid, and the date is within the time frame, you are able to accept an upload.

Some points to note:

- This is a **very** simple system, but might be exactly what you need.
- You should avoid MD5 for the hashing function, take something like SHA1 instead.
- For the link sent to the Writer, you could "obfuscate" the parameter names, ie, call them "k" for the "key" and "d" for the "authDate".
- For the date, you could chose another format, more "cryptic", like the unix epoch.
- Finally, you can encode the parameters with something like "base64" (or simply apply some character replacing function like rot13 for instance, but that take digits into account aswell) just in order to make them more difficult to guessing
- Just for completeness, in the validation script you can also check if the Writer has already sent a file on the time frame, thus making it impossible to him to send many files within the time frame.

I have recently implemented something like this twice on the company I work for, for two completely different uses. Once you get the idea, it is **extremelly** simple to implement it -- maybe less than 10 lines of code for the whole key-generation and validation process.

On one of them, the agent equivalent to your Writer had no account into the system (actually it would be his first contact with the system) -- there was only his "profile" on the system, managed by someone else. In this case, you would have to include the "Writer"'s id on the parameters to the "Upload" script aswell.

I hope this helps, and that it was clear enough. If I find the time, I will blog about it with an working example on some language.

Comment: That was great Bruno! Very informative, thank you very much! Just subscribed to your blog :) 
Thanks again